# Matlab - count conditioning on previous value

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, probability

I have a n x m matrix, and I have associated quantiles for each column (for example for m = 3)

-0.0627      -0.0564      -0.0413

How can I count the number of times Xn+1 descends below each associated quantile given that Xn has, for each column?

I could use sum ( X =< -0.0627) for the first column for example but how to model the condition that it should only count if the previous value was also below -0.0627?

I am sorry if the answer is too obvious or the question not clear but I am only starting with matlab.

Thanks!!!

Comment: It is not super clear what you are asking. Can you make a bigger example with expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

If X is a column, you can use `&` to join your two conditions that Xn and Xn+1 must be below -0.0627 like so:

```
Xn = X(1:end-1);
Xnplus1 = X(2:end);
sum(Xn <= -0.0627 &  Xnplus1 <= -0.0627)
```

Comment: +1 Use `bsxfun` to work with all columns at once (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
data = [ -1 -1  0
         -2 -2  0
          0 -3 -1
         -2  0  0 ];
quant = [-0.0627 -0.0564 -0.0413];

R = bsxfun(@lt, data, quant);
result = sum(R(1:end-1,:) & R(2:end,:));
```

This gives the result `[1 2 0]` in my example.

Comment: thank you, I used that it has given me excatly what I wanted.